# How can you disable IPv6 in Docker on CentOS7?

Tags: ipv6, docker, centos7

I have tried the normal methods (e.g. https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6#head-d47139912868bcb9d754441ecb6a8a10d41781df). And even though `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6` returns 1 on my host system, it always returns 0 inside my container.

Thanks!

Comment: Try add `ipv6.disable=1` to your grub line

Answer (score 3):

There issue in docker: [#20569](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20569)
In this issue there [mato's comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20569#issuecomment-248601846) that docker option `--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` partialy fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, @slipper's solution didn't work for me. I had to do this

```sh
# Disable IPv6
❯ sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
❯ sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
❯ service docker restart

# Test
❯ docker run -dit -p 8080:80 --name test vikas027/site-counter
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                  NAMES
e9dd5b0ce0ea   vikas027/site-counter                                         "supervisord --confi…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   test
```

This is my docker version

```
❯ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.15.14
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Nov 17 03:05:36 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.15.14
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Nov 17 03:06:14 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0
  GitCommit:        84113eef6fc27af1b01b3181f31bbaf708715301
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```